# NativeStorage don't work in app.component

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-nativestorage

I have the NativeStorage plugin installed in my project, it works perfectly fine in all of my pages.
But it does not want to work in the Side menu of the app.component. This tells me that it is not installed even though it correctly installed as indicated on the documentation for it.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this might be because:

1. You didn't insert the plugin inside Providers on app.module.ts
2. The plugin is not compatible with the platform you are using (which i doubt, cause it's compatible with iOS, Android and Browser).
3. Sometimes the app tries to use a plugin before the platform has installed everything needed. I would highly recommend use pltaform plugin to see if its ready to start working. Use *platform.ready()* as you can see in this example:

   ```
    this.platform.ready.then(async (data)=> {
          //do something here
    });
   ```

And finally, just tell you that sometimes your compilation fails or leaves a plugin behind, so if this doesn't work try removing the platform you are using and adding it again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The plugin is correctly indicated in the providers on app.module.ts. It's a native plugin in I don't think it's incompatible with iOS or Android. I added platform.ready, for the translation it works but still the same problem with the NativeStorage.

Comment: That's weird... try 'ionic cordova platform rm android' and 'ionic cordova platform add android'. Sometimes reinstalling the platform builds it correctly.